# Postgres query to combine two column values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a postgres table with the following data:

```
hostname | ip
---------+--------
a1       | 198.162.4.2
a1       | 198.162.7.5
a2       | 10.43.243.4
a3       | 10.3.1.1
```

I want to copy the values from table tmp to table abc in psql.
I want to have an sql insert command to display the hostname_ip in hostname column like below:

```
hostname | ip
---------+--------
a1_198.162.4.2 | 198.162.4.2    
a1_198.162.7.5 | 198.162.7.5
a2_10.43.243.4 | 10.43.243.4
a3_10.3.1.1    | 10.3.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below

```
insert into abc(hostname,ip)
select (hostname || '_' || ip) as hostname,ip from tmp;
```

Comment: Do you mean update same table? Yes it is possible

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `CONCAT_WS` here:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS('_', hostname, ip) AS hostname, ip
FROM yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT CONCAT(hostname,'_',ip) as hostname,ip FROM table;